# Bold Row when a match is found in a predetermined list in excel macro?

Tags: excel, vba

Is there a way to write an excel macro where:

1) finds a match in a predetermined list

2) bolds the length of the row before until there is a blank cell

For example if the word is Cat in A1 is part of my list, I want columns `A:E` bolded for that row but not `F` because that's a blank cell.

I'm finding myself having to bold rows of data when I find a word that matches a list that I have and it's very tedious since I can't bold the entire row just the columns of data that belong to that dataset.

The bolding will only be left to right.

Comment: Post your current code and tell us where it fails so we can help you.

Comment: I don't have any... I was wondering if it is possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set up your spreadsheet like this
 [image: setup]
Then insert this code to a **`Module`** in VBE <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>F11</kbd>

```
Sub BoldNeighbouringCells()

    Dim myList As Range
    ' your keyword list is now A2 til last row in column A
    Set myList = Range("A2:A" & Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row))

    Dim dataRange As Range
    ' your raw data is B2 til last row in column B
    Set dataRange = Range("B2:B" & Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row))

    Dim x As Range, y As Range, i As Long
    ' iterate over both collections of data and look for matches
    For Each x In myList
        For Each y In dataRange
            ' compare names from myList against Data Keys
            If StrComp(x.Text, y.Text, vbTextCompare) = 0 Then
                ' bold match
                y.Font.Bold = True
                ' now, iterate through offset ( all columns < F (4))
                ' check if each cell is not empty then bold the text
                For i = 1 To 4
                    If Not IsEmpty(y.Offset(0, i)) Then
                        y.Offset(0, i).Font.Bold = True
                    End If
                Next i
            End If
        Next
    Next

End Sub
```

Then hit <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>F8</kbd> to **`View Macros`** and run the **`BoldNeighbouringCells()`** Macro

If everything goes fine you should end up with results like in the below snapshot
[image: result]

Comment: Wow Thanks so much! this works! I do have very large sets of data though and I'm wondering if there's an easier way to do those rather than manually changing the row numbers every time? The data sets are about the same amount of columns across (11) but the number of rows in the sets vary and I have about 20 of them in the same worksheet. If it's just easier to manually change the rows, I'll do so, thanks! So for example if your example data I had 20 of those to the right and bottom of where your data currently is. it's just easy to miss bolding some rows when you looking at so much data.

Comment: @user2532928 you can paint the interior for easier recognition. Change this `y.Offset(0, i).Font.Bold = True` to `y.Offset(0, i).Interior.Color = RGB(110, 120, 40)`

Comment: Oh thanks! I do need the bold though, I just need to do it repetitively across different data sets. I'll just change the columns and row number manually then, thanks!

Comment: @user2532928 oh sorry, I have misunderstood your first comment. I have changed the code accordingly to automatically get the last item in the column A and B